# Java conditions- Branching statements

Tags: java

I need to write a program that the bus will fit under bridges. The first line of the input contains the height of the bus and the number of bridges under which the bus passes. The second line contains the heights of these bridges.

I need should output "Will not crash" if everything will be all right; otherwise, output "Will crash on bridge i" (where i is a number of a bridge) into which the bus will crash. If the height of a bridge equals the height of the bus, the bus will crash.

until now I have written:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int busHeight = s.nextInt();
        int bridgeCount = s.nextInt();
        int bridgeHeight = 0;
        boolean willCrash = false;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bridgeCount; i++) {
            bridgeHeight = s.nextInt();

            if (bridgeHeight == busHeight || bridgeHeight < busHeight) {
                willCrash = true;
                count++;
            }
            if (bridgeHeight == busHeight || bridgeHeight < busHeight) {
                willCrash = true;
                count++;
            }
            if (!(bridgeCount - count != 0 && willCrash)) {
                System.out.println("Will not crash");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + (bridgeCount - count));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Test input:

211 5

871 205 123 871 1681

Correct output:

Will crash on bridge 2

Your code output:

Will not crash

I've been monitoring the program's launch and it's coming out prematurely. Please give me some tips on what to change.

Comment: The `break;` statement will cause the loop to end after the first iteration. Why did you put that in there? And why is the whole `if (bridgeHeight == ...` in there two times?

Comment: This isn't relevant, but I'll just note that `bridgeHeight == busHeight || bridgeHeight < busHeight` can be written as `bridgeHeight <= busHeight`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that solves my problem. Gets data correctly and displays when the bus does not cross the bridge

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int heightOfBus = scan.nextInt();

        int heightOfBridges;

        int willCrash = 0;

        if (scan.hasNext()) {
            int numOfBridges = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 1; scan.hasNext() ; i++) {

            heightOfBridges = scan.nextInt();

            if (heightOfBridges <= heightOfBus) {
                willCrash = 1;
                System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (willCrash == 0) {
            System.out.println("Will not crash");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if (bridgeHeight == busHeight || bridgeHeight < busHeight) {
```

you can use

```
if (bridgeHeight <= busHeight) { // Bridge height is smaller or equal to the height of the bus
```

If the above if statement is true, you have concluded that the bus will crash, so you can print:

```
System.out.println("Will crash on bridge " + i+1); // i+1 because i = 0 on the first bridge,
// i = 1 on the second bridge and so on.
return; // End the program.
```

At the end of the loop, you have checked every bridge and conclused that the bus will not crash and you can print

```
System.out.println("Will not crash");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't really solve my problem.

Comment: @Peter you're right, this does not solve the problem. The solution you posted is what I meant to describe here, but with my solution it will say "Will not crash" in any case. But I'm glad you managed to work it out, good job!

Comment: Instead of `break;` it should say `return;` in the loop. This stops the entire program after it has conclused that the bus will crash. Otherwise it will eventually reach the part where it prints "Will not crash" in any case. Feel free to mark your own answer as the solution.